# Swift Inverse FFT (IFFT) Via Chirp Z-Transform (CZT)

Tags: swift, fft, ifft

For arbitrary sample sizes (samples not equal to 2^N), I have been able to implement the FFT via the chirp Z-transform (CZT) using iOS Accelerate's FFT function (that only works for samples equal to 2^N).

The results are good and match the Matlab FFT output for any arbitrary length sequence (signal). I paste the code below.

My next challenge is to use iOS Accelerate's FFT function (that only works for samples equal to 2^N) for accomplishing an inverse FFT on arbitrary sample sizes (samples not equal to 2^N).

Since my CZT accomplishes arbitrary length FFT now (see below), I am hoping that an inverse CZT (ICZT) would accomplish an arbitrary length IFFT using iOS Accelerate's FFT function (that only works for samples equal to 2^N).

Any suggestions/guidence?

```
// FFT IOS ACCELERATE FRAMEWORK (works only for 2^N samples)
import Accelerate

public func fft(x: [Double], y: [Double], type: String) -> ([Double], [Double]) {

    var real = [Double](x)

    var imaginary = [Double](y)

    var splitComplex = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imaginary)

    let length = vDSP_Length(floor(log2(Float(real.count))))

    let radix = FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)

    let weights = vDSP_create_fftsetupD(length, radix)

    switch type.lowercased() {

    case ("fft"): // CASE FFT
        vDSP_fft_zipD(weights!, &splitComplex, 1, length, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))
        vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(weights)

    case ("ifft"): // CASE INVERSE FFT
        vDSP_fft_zipD(weights!, &splitComplex, 1, length, FFTDirection(FFT_INVERSE))
        vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(weights)
        real = real.map({ $0 / Double(x.count) }) // Normalize IFFT by sample count
        imaginary = imaginary.map({ $0 / Double(x.count) }) // Normalize IFFT by sample count

    default: // DEFAULT CASE (FFT)
        vDSP_fft_zipD(weights!, &splitComplex, 1, length, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))
        vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(weights)
    }

    return (real, imaginary)
}

// END FFT IOS ACCELERATE FRAMEWORK (works only for 2^N samples)

// DEFINE COMPLEX NUMBERS
struct Complex<T: FloatingPoint> {
    let real: T
    let imaginary: T
    static func +(lhs: Complex<T>, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        return Complex(real: lhs.real + rhs.real, imaginary: lhs.imaginary + rhs.imaginary)
    }

    static func -(lhs: Complex<T>, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        return Complex(real: lhs.real - rhs.real, imaginary: lhs.imaginary - rhs.imaginary)
    }

    static func *(lhs: Complex<T>, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        return Complex(real: lhs.real * rhs.real - lhs.imaginary * rhs.imaginary,
                       imaginary: lhs.imaginary * rhs.real + lhs.real * rhs.imaginary)
    }
}

extension Complex: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch (real, imaginary) {
        case (_, 0):
            return "\(real)"
        case (0, _):
            return "\(imaginary)i"
        case (_, let b) where b < 0:
            return "\(real) - \(abs(imaginary))i"
        default:
            return "\(real) + \(imaginary)i"
        }
    }
}

// DEFINE COMPLEX NUMBERS

// DFT BASED ON CHIRP Z TRANSFORM (CZT)
public func dft(x: [Double]) -> ([Double], [Double]) {

    let m = x.count // number of samples

    var N: [Double] = Array(stride(from: Double(0), through: Double(m - 1), by: 1.0))

    N = N.map({ $0 + Double(m) })

    var NM: [Double] = Array(stride(from: Double(-(m - 1)), through: Double(m - 1), by: 1.0))

    NM = NM.map({ $0 + Double(m) })

    var M: [Double] = Array(stride(from: Double(0), through: Double(m - 1), by: 1.0))

    M = M.map({ $0 + Double(m) })

    let nfft = Int(pow(2, ceil(log2(Double(m + m - 1))))) // fft pad

    var p1: [Double] = Array(stride(from: Double(-(m - 1)), through: Double(m - 1), by: 1.0))

    p1 = (zip(p1, p1).map(*)).map({ $0 / Double(2) }) // W = WR + j*WI has to be raised to power p1

    var WR = [Double]()
    var WI = [Double]()

    for i in 0 ..< p1.count { // Use De Moivre's formula to raise to power p1
        WR.append(cos(p1[i] * 2.0 * M_PI / Double(m)))
        WI.append(sin(-p1[i] * 2.0 * M_PI / Double(m)))
    }

    var aaR = [Double]()
    var aaI = [Double]()

    for j in 0 ..< N.count {
        aaR.append(WR[Int(N[j] - 1)] * x[j])
        aaI.append(WI[Int(N[j] - 1)] * x[j])
    }

    let la = nfft - aaR.count

    let pad: [Double] = Array(repeating: 0, count: la) // 1st zero padding

    aaR += pad

    aaI += pad

    let (fgr, fgi) = fft(x: aaR, y: aaI, type: "fft") // 1st FFT

    var bbR = [Double]()
    var bbI = [Double]()

    for k in 0 ..< NM.count {
        bbR.append((WR[Int(NM[k] - 1)]) / (((WR[Int(NM[k] - 1)])) * ((WR[Int(NM[k] - 1)])) + ((WI[Int(NM[k] - 1)])) * ((WI[Int(NM[k] - 1)])))) // take reciprocal
        bbI.append(-(WI[Int(NM[k] - 1)]) / (((WR[Int(NM[k] - 1)])) * ((WR[Int(NM[k] - 1)])) + ((WI[Int(NM[k] - 1)])) * ((WI[Int(NM[k] - 1)])))) // take reciprocal
    }

    let lb = nfft - bbR.count

    let pad2: [Double] = Array(repeating: 0, count: lb) // 2nd zero padding

    bbR += pad2

    bbI += pad2

    let (fwr, fwi) = fft(x: bbR, y: bbI, type: "fft") // 2nd FFT

    let fg = zip(fgr, fgi).map { Complex<Double>(real: $0, imaginary: $1) } // complexN 1

    let fw = zip(fwr, fwi).map { Complex<Double>(real: $0, imaginary: $1) } // complexN 2

    let cc = zip(fg, fw).map { $0 * $1 } // multiply above 2 complex numbers fg * fw

    var ccR = cc.map { $0.real } // real part (vector) of complex multiply

    var ccI = cc.map { $0.imaginary } // imag part (vector) of complex multiply

    let lc = nfft - ccR.count

    let pad3: [Double] = Array(repeating: 0, count: lc) // 3rd zero padding

    ccR += pad3

    ccI += pad3

    let (ggr, ggi) = fft(x: ccR, y: ccI, type: "ifft") // 3rd FFT (IFFT)

    var GGr = [Double]()
    var GGi = [Double]()
    var W2r = [Double]()
    var W2i = [Double]()

    for v in 0 ..< M.count {
        GGr.append(ggr[Int(M[v] - 1)])
        GGi.append(ggi[Int(M[v] - 1)])
        W2r.append(WR[Int(M[v] - 1)])
        W2i.append(WI[Int(M[v] - 1)])
    }

    let ggg = zip(GGr, GGi).map { Complex<Double>(real: $0, imaginary: $1) }

    let www = zip(W2r, W2i).map { Complex<Double>(real: $0, imaginary: $1) }

    let y = zip(ggg, www).map { $0 * $1 }

    let yR = y.map { $0.real } // FFT real part (output vector)

    let yI = y.map { $0.imaginary } // FFT imag part (output vector)

    return (yR, yI)
}

// END DFT BASED ON CHIRP Z TRANSFORM (CZT)

// CHIRP DFT (CZT) TEST
let x: [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // arbitrary sample size
let (fftR, fftI) = dft(x: x)
print("DFT Real Part:", fftR)
print(" ")
print("DFT Imag Part:", fftI)

// Matches Matlab FFT Output
// DFT Real Part: [15.0, -2.5000000000000018, -2.5000000000000013, -2.4999999999999991, -2.499999999999996]
// DFT Imag Part: [-1.1102230246251565e-16, 3.4409548011779334, 0.81229924058226477, -0.81229924058226599, -3.4409548011779356]

// END CHIRP DFT (CZT) TEST
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, so many questions. Are you using CZT just to get non-power-of-two FFTs using Accelerate’s FFT (which only works for power-of-two)? Why don’t you just use another FFT library that’s not constrained, like FFTW or another Apple library? Any speedup achieved by using Accelerate under the hood will likely be completely obviated by the enormous computational burden of the CZT (setting up all those exponentials).

Comment: If you really really really really really want to use ICZT to get non-power-of-two IFFTs this way, then make your `dft` function accept a `type: String` argument like your `fft`. When `type` is `ifft`, I think all you need is to flip the sign here: `WI.append(sin(-p1[i] * 2.0 * M_PI / Double(m)))`, have negative for forward, and positive for inverse. I *think* that’s all you need to do to change the direction of CZT→ICZT.

Comment: See this Matlab/Octave code: https://gist.github.com/fasiha/42a21405de92ea46f59e The demo shows how to use `czt2` to do `fft` with the third argument to `czt2`, called `w`, being `exp(-2j * pi / Nup)`. To make it match `ifft`, just change the third argument to `exp(+2j * pi / Nup)`, i.e., conjugate `w`. That’s what flipping the sign in the exponent for `WI` does.

Comment: Also, consider using https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat

Comment: You are a star Ahmed Fasih! Changing the sinusoidal sign at "WI.append.." and normalizing the final outputs by sample count accomplished the ICZT / IFFT. Performance looks ok but I will look at other options (like Swift format) that you have suggested. Also, I will try to incorporate your more efficient czt2 function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer to close this question—

If you’re sure you want to use an ICZT as an equivalent of IFFT, then make your `dft` function accept a `type: String` argument like your `fft`. When `type` is `ifft`, all you need is to flip the sign here:

`WI.append(sin(-p1[i] * 2.0 * M_PI / Double(m)))`

Leave it negative for forward FFT, and positive for inverse FFT (IFFT).

---

Here’s some Octave/Matlab code I wrote to demonstrate CZT: [gist.github.com/fasiha/42a21405de92ea46f59e](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/42a21405de92ea46f59e). The demo shows how to use `czt2` to do `fft`. The third argument to `czt2` (called `w` in the code) is `exp(-2j * pi / Nup)` for FFT. Just conjugate it to `exp(+2j * pi / Nup)` to get IFFT.

That’s what flipping the sign in the `sin` in `WI` does.